# How to change the onclick of a button to another function using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, onclick

This is my first question I'm asking. Is it possible to change the `onclick="change()"` to another function like `onclick="change1()"`

My code is like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeSrc()" id="a1"><img src="images/transparent-arrow-hi.png" style="position:absolute; top:525px; left:1000px; height:50px; width:50px;" ></a>
<img src="images/keyboard.png" id="pic1">
<img src="images/mouse1.png" id="pic2">
<img src="images/PCstand.png" id="pic3">
<img src="images/monitor.png" id="pic4">
```

My Javascript is as follows:

```
<script>
function changeSrc() {
document.getElementById('pic1').src="images/robber1.jpg";
document.getElementById('pic2').src="images/guarding entrance 1.jpg";
document.getElementById('pic3').src="images/Lock.ico";
document.getElementById('pic4').src="images/Number pads.jpg";
}
</script>
```

This works so far in changing the img src , But I want to click the same button many times to change the img src to others.

So its like this button that when onclick , can call the first function to change the img src and at the same time prepare the onclick to call the second funtion.

Is that even possible?

I can add more code if needed.

Answer (score 2):

you can have counter and every time call your function increase number of counter and select what actions you need.or you can use switch in changeSrc function

```
<script>
var counter = 0;
function changeSrc() {
 if(counter==0){
    document.getElementById('pic1').src="images/robber1.jpg";
    document.getElementById('pic2').src="images/guarding entrance 1.jpg";
    document.getElementById('pic3').src="images/Lock.ico";
    document.getElementById('pic4').src="images/Number pads.jpg";
}
 if(counter==1){
    document.getElementById('pic1').src="images/robber2.jpg";
    document.getElementById('pic2').src="images/guarding entrance 2.jpg";
    document.getElementById('pic3').src="images/Lock2.ico";
    document.getElementById('pic4').src="images/Number pads2.jpg";
}
    counter++;
}
</script>
```

if your images have pattern like numbers you can do this

```
<script>
var counter = 0;
function changeSrc() {
    document.getElementById('pic1').src="images/robber"+counter+".jpg";
    document.getElementById('pic2').src="images/guarding entrance "+counter+".jpg";;
    document.getElementById('pic3').src="images/Lock "+counter+".ico";;
    document.getElementById('pic4').src="images/Number pads"+counter+".jpg";;    
 counter++;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where in the question has OP mentioned that the image names have same pattern and is distinguished by the appending number 1 and 2 ?

Comment: Also what will happen if counter is 3 or 4? I do not think this is an appropriate answer and also why this has been vote up?

Comment: @AKA user didn't mentioned any type of image,every type that he likes can insert.

Comment: If this is so then for need to mention that for every counter value, not just for counter ==0 or counter==1. Also the OP asked "Is it possible to change the onclick="change()" to another function like onclick="change1()". Not the one you answered.

Comment: @AKA its no need.user want to change their image src.its no need to call another functin

Comment: How are you so sure that the image name contains the counter value?

Comment: "if your images have pattern like numbers you can do this", How can you assume this? You need to clarify all these things in the question comment before you answer hypothetically.

Comment: Im not sure.and its no need my friend.when i put counter it mean he can set every image address.its just sample.as you can see I updated my post that if he have counter in his images he can use the second function that its more appropriate

Comment: my friend if said `if` it means `if`

Comment: If it is so then many people here can assume their own and say, if it is so do this, if it is not so do this. You need to be on to the point with the question and not assume yourself.

Comment: Well then i can also say, if you have this then do this. This is not how we answer and that is not the OP asked for .

Comment: Also how can you assume that 

  document.getElementById('pic3').src="images/Lock.ico";
    document.getElementById('pic4').src="images/Number pads.jpg";
Will be same all time with any counter value? Another assumption...

Comment: look.in first answer my anser is  not related to counters.he can set every src he need,if he know how many function he need he also know how many counter he should set

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. This has helped me solved my problem. I wanted to change the images when a button is clicked and when it is clicked again , a new set of pictures will appear. This method would be faster than just making separate different pages just for the images which would just mess things up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet to dynamically associate and change the `onclick` function of the element.

```js
function changeSrc(_this){
 //associate function change1 inside changeSrc
 $(_this).attr('onclick','change1(this)');
}

function change1(_this){
//associate function change2 inside change1
  $(_this).attr('onclick','change2(this)');
  console.log('Iniside Change1()')
}

function change2(_this){
//associate function change3 inside change2
  $(_this).attr('onclick','change3(this)');
  console.log('Iniside Change2()')
}

function change3(_this){
  console.log('Iniside Change3()')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="changeSrc(this)" id="a1"><img src="images/transparent-arrow-hi.png" style="position:absolute; top:525px; left:1000px; height:50px; width:50px;" >click</a>
```